# How to fix linux-tools broken due to interrupt during Ubuntu upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

I am upgrading Ubuntu upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 but I mistakenly reboot the machine in the middle. I try to upgrade the system again by following the commands in option 2 in this [post](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-to-ubuntu-18-04#ftoc-heading-6).

1.1. Update the software packages repository list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                 
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                              
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [55.2 kB]                                    
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [60.9 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [297 kB]             
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [302 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Fetched 986 kB in 2s (499 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
```

1.2. Then, upgrade already installed packages and let the system handle package dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-4.15.0-46-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-46 but it is not installed
 linux-tools-4.15.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-50 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-tools-4.15.0-46-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-tools-4.15.0-46-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-46.49).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-4.15.0-46-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-46 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-tools-4.15.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-50 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-4.15.0-46-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-46 but it is not installed
 linux-tools-4.15.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-50 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

1.3. Finally, free up disk space by removing all unnecessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-4.15.0-46-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-46 but it is not installed
 linux-tools-4.15.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-50 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

2.1. Run the command for installing Update Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

But I get errors from linux-tools broken.

```
(base) $ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:18.04.11.13).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-4.15.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-43 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-tools-4.15.0-46-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-46 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-tools-4.15.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-tools-4.15.0-50 but it is not going to be installed
```

```
(base) xxx@yyy:~$ sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu fonts-deva-extra fonts-kalapi fonts-smc fonts-smc-anjalioldlipi fonts-smc-chilanka fonts-smc-dyuthi fonts-smc-karumbi fonts-smc-keraleeyam fonts-smc-manjari fonts-smc-meera fonts-smc-rachana
  fonts-smc-raghumalayalamsans fonts-smc-suruma fonts-smc-uroob gcc-6-base:i386 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gnome-orca icoutils idle-python2.7 ipython3-qtconsole katepart kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-breeze
  kde-style-breeze-qt4 kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools libamd2.4.1 libass5 libatk1.0-dev libattica0.4 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2
  libavutil-ffmpeg54 libblas-common libbluray1 libbotan-1.10-1 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libcamd2.4.1 libcapnp-0.5.3 libccolamd2.9.1 libcholmod3.0.6 libchromaprint0 libclang1-3.6 libconfig-file-perl
  libcxsparse3.1.4 libdlrestrictions1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgflags2v5 libgl2ps0 libglpk36 libgpgme++2v5 libgtk2.0-dev libgtkglext1 libhdf5-10 libhdf5-cpp-11 libirs-export141 libisccfg-export140 libjasper-dev
  libkactivities6 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkf5style5 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4
  libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkxmlrpcclient4 libllvm3.6v5 libmimic0 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 liboctave3 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5
  libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-gpu2.4v5 libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect2.4v5
  libopencv-ocl2.4v5 libopencv-photo2.4v5 libopencv-stitching2.4v5 libopencv-superres2.4v5 libopencv-ts2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5 libopencv-videostab2.4v5 libopencv2.4-jni libopenjpeg5 libpango1.0-dev libphonon4
  libpixman-1-dev libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libprotoc9v5 libpython3.5-dbg libpython3.5-dev libqbscore1 libqbsqtprofilesetup1 libqca2 libqca2-plugins libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n
  libqt5clucene5 libqtwebkit4 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsodium18 libsolid4 libsox2 libsrtp0 libstreamanalyzer0v5 libstreams0v5 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3 libthreadweaver4 libumfpack5.7.1 libunwind-dev libva1
  libwebpdemux1 libwildmidi1 libx264-148 libx265-79 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev linux-generic linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-4.15.0-140
  linux-headers-4.15.0-140-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-46 linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-50 linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-modules-4.15.0-140-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-140-generic linux-tools-4.4.0-210 linux-tools-4.4.0-210-generic ntrack-module-libnl-0 orca oxideqt-codecs-extra oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer-common
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript pylint python-astroid python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-cairo python-concurrent.futures python-configparser python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-gobject-2
  python-gtk2 python-isort python-lazy-object-proxy python-logilab-common python-mccabe python-singledispatch python-spyderlib-doc python-wrapt python3-pep8 python3-spyderlib python3.5-dbg python3.5-dev
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-4.15.0-46 linux-tools-4.15.0-50
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-4.15.0-46 linux-tools-4.15.0-50
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,255 kB of archives.
After this operation, 41.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 487109 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-4.15.0-46_4.15.0-46.49_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.15.0-46 (4.15.0-46.49) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-46_4.15.0-46.49_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libcpupower.so.4.15.0-46', which is also in package linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-46 4.15.0-46.49~16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-4.15.0-50_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.15.0-50 (4.15.0-50.54) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-50_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libcpupower.so.4.15.0-50', which is also in package linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-50 4.15.0-50.54~16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-46_4.15.0-46.49_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-50_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The last option I have is to reinstall the operating system but it will erase my data or I need to backup a lot of data which takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062171/dpkg-deb-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-46_4.15.0-46.49_amd64.deb
```

```
$ sudo apt -f install
```

Next,

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-50_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb
```

```
$ sudo apt -f install
```